# Composer shows "nothing to update" but there is a new version of the module

Tags: updating, composer

I am managing a Drupal 8 site in Composer.  Commerce 2.0 was just released; I currently have 2.0-rc2 installed on my site.

This is my `composer.json`

```
"drupal/commerce": "^2.0@RC",

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

To update, I ran `composer update drupal/commerce --with-dependencies`, which gave me this result:

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Drupal\Component\Utility\Random" was found in both "$baseDir . '/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Random.php" and "/mnt/c/Users/x/d/mysite/vendor/drupal/drupal-driver/src/Drupal/Component/Utility/Random.php", the first will be used.
Removing packages services cache file:
/mnt/c/Users/x/d/mysite/vendor/drupal/console/extend.console.uninstall.services.yml
Creating packages services cache file:
/mnt/c/Users/x/d/mysite/vendor/drupal/console/extend.console.uninstall.services.yml
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
```

So Commerce does not get updated to 2.0 (I already updated all the dependencies to their latest versions.)

I thought it might be a caching issue so I ran `composer clearcache` and then attempted to update commerce again, but I got the same result (nothing to update).

I thought it might be an issue with the composer module list being out of date, but Commerce 2.0 was released more than 48 hours ago.  So what can I do to get composer working in this case?

**EDIT**

My repo is based on the [Drops 8 Composer](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/example-drops-8-composer) repo from Pantheon, which is in turn based on `drupal-composer/drupal-project`.

Deleting the `/vendor` directory and running `composer update` gives me this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Changing `composer.json` to `"drupal/core": "^8.4@RC"` `"symfony/css-selector": "~3.2"` also results in the same error.

But, running `composer install` or running `composer update drupal/modulename` allows me to install the site and update individual modules (except Commerce) without any problem.

Comment: Is it based on the `drupal-composer/drupal-project`? I had some issues as well (though not the same output as yours), but I've managed to get it to work by updating the require section to include `"drupal/core": "^8.4@RC"`, `"drush/drush": "~9.0",` and set `"symfony/css-selector": "~3.2"` in require-dev.

Comment: Try this, delete the vendor directory `rm -rf vendor/` and then run `composer update`

Comment: @NoSssweat  It didn't work, unfortunately.  Got a "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Comment: @Neograph734 It's based on a Pantheon repo that is in turn based on `drupal-composer/drupal-project`.  I tried what you suggested but then I get Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Neograph734 for pointing me in the right direction.

I needed to require Drupal 8.4-rc2 and drush 9, and then Commerce 2 arrived automatically.

Drush 9 appears to be a requirement for the 8.4 core update.